# DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause in yii

Tags: sql, sql-server, yii, yii2

I am using the Yii framework (version 2.0.36) and SQL Server for my project and hit a roadblock with the error:

> Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The target table 'status_comment' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.
> The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO [status_comment] ([application_id], [status], [created_by]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (329, 13, 61).

I just set up a normal trigger having the same columns on insert and update but I get this error on inserts only.

Code in YII:

```
    $status = new StatusComment();
    $status->application_id = $id;
    $status->status = $application->status;
    $status->save();

    // created_by gets saved using BlameableBehavior::class
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Do you have any triggers on the `status_comment` table? Seems like you could be running an older version of Yii because this was raised in [Issue 18221](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/18221) and fixed in [Issue 18214](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/18214) back in 2020.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Yes I do have triggers on the status_comment table. Thanks for the help. Just curious, by any chance is there a temporary workaround for this?